# Volley Cache using ETag

Tags: android, rest, caching, android-volley

I'm using Volley library and I can't to set up caching properly.

Server sends me json object, expiration and ETAg.. I want to Voley save this object in cache and in next request for this object use request to the server including ETag in the header. If response will be 304 Not Modified, then it should use cached resource and if it will be 200 OK, it should use new resource from the server.

I'm watching communication via Fidler and I can see that Volley doesn't send request at all (if the cache isn't expired) or if it is expired it sends new request with If-None-Match + etag string.. and server always response with 200ok

Comment: ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no..  If anybody know the solution please share it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revalidate on each request, you should set the max age to 0 so the cache entry is always expired.

And if the server always response with 200 OK, check the cause in the server, because if the request has the correct Etag has nothing to do with volley.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. When I set max age to 0, server sends back 200 Ok answer and no-cache;Expires:-1 Volley then don't use cache at all. BUT when I set max age to 1 (1 second) then it start working, but still not perfectly. I send first request, it sends me 200 Ok back. The second response is finally 304 No-change :-) It's super! Unfortunately, when I send another third request it again sends me 200 and after that 304 and so on.. The another problem is when Volley use his cached data, there are problems with coding.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that Volley recieve ETag with response and uses it for next request, where server returns 304 Not-Modified, but on the next request Volley doesn't use this ETag (If-Modified_Since) again! So the server returns 200 Ok with the same ETag as before.. The problem is on Volley side, but I can't figure out how to solve it?

Comment: One more note.. The server doesn't send ETag in 304 Not-Modified response. But I gues it is normal behaviour, isn't it?

Comment: it's not, server should always return ETag, quoted from http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html (you could check how this server return 304 and etag header if you ask for the same html again). "Instead, if the request method was GET or HEAD, the server SHOULD respond with a 304 (Not Modified) response, including the cache- related header fields (particularly ETag) of one of the entities that matched. For all other request methods, the server MUST respond with a status of 412 (Precondition Failed)."

Comment: I'm using AspNetWebApi-OutputCache https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache and there is no option how to set this.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that when i use

```
BasicHttpClient httpClient = new BasicHttpClient();

httpClient.addHeader("If-None-Match", "vENFxg");
```

It always return 200.

but if I use

```
httpClient.addHeader("If-None-Match", "\"vENFxg\"");
```

it works, and I get 304(HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED).

You can try below with volley.

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    mHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mHeaders.put("If-None-Match", "\"vENFxg\"");

    return mHeaders;
}
```

let me know if worked.

I assume that you store the volley response if somewhere in your app because you needed etag.

In this case, I would prefer to save the etag in somewhere(like Preferences).
I do use volley with some of simple request.

Volley's presentation also mention "volley perfectly fine for doing those same kinds of operations in the background. But it really excels at the intersection of UI and network. It's not for everything, though."

And sorry, my English is poor.

Comment: What is **vENFxg**?