# How to use Etags with Volley

Tags: android, android-volley, etag

I haven't been able to find a direct answer to this question anywhere, so it's time to finally ask:

Does Volley take care of sending ETags in GET requests?

After researching online, I vaguely think it does, however, I'm not sure. I have an API that uses ETags. In my code, I already account for the cached response:

```
String url = Uri.parse(Statics.baseURL + "/users/" + Statics.user.getUser_id() + "/items").buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("token",Statics.token)
            .build().toString();

    // Check to see if the response got cached
    if(requestQueue.getCache().get(url)!=null){
        //response exists
        String cachedResponse = new String(requestQueue.getCache().get(url).data);
        processItems(cachedResponse);
    }

    Request request = new JsonRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            null,
            new ErrorListener(context)){
        @Override
        protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            // Only process the items if the response is modified
            if(!response.notModified)
                processItems(new String(response.data));
            return null;
        }

    };

    requestQueue.add(request);
```

I would only like to handle the data from the API if the data is modified, but I always get a `response code = 200` and `notModified = false` back.

**I am not manually setting the `If-None-Match` header because I was hoping Volley would keep track of it for me. Is this correct?**

Comment: see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272348/volley-cache-using-etag?rq=1

Comment: @njzk2 I did see that question already. I am asking if Volley will somehow send and handle the Etags for me? The answer to that question is 1) not Volley 2) is manually sending the If-None-Match header

Comment: quoting the question : `I'm watching communication via Fidler and I can see that Volley [...] sends new request with If-None-Match + etag string`. I suggest you check the content of the request either using a proxy or on the server side.

Comment: also, volley takes care of the cache as well.

Comment: Ok. Do you know how to make it keep track? If I send the etag, I correctly received a 304, however, Volley is not sending it.

Comment: it may have to do with the Cache-Control and Expires headers sent by the server

Comment: Looking into it more, I think Volley caches things by the "If-Modified-Since" header, not the etag

Comment: in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java line 194, volley adds the etag as a If-None-Match header.